# How do I use a keyboard event to play a sound using a URLrequest?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, jquery-animate

I have the basic code where I click an icon using a mouse event to fetch a url that has a streaming radio to start and stop but I want to make it a keyboard event. I do not know how to do this. I am using adobe animate. I know how to make an symbol disappear using keyup/keydown commands but I do not know how to assign a keyboard event in place of a mouse event. The end result is a radio where I can toggle between each station pressing assigned letters on the keyboard. this is my code:

```
button_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToPlayStopSound_4);

var fl_SC_4:SoundChannel;


var fl_ToPlay_4:Boolean = true;

function fl_ClickToPlayStopSound_4(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(fl_ToPlay_4)
    {
        var s:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("http://64.71.79.181:5234/stream"));
        fl_SC_4 = s.play();
    }
    else
    {
        fl_SC_4.stop();
    }
    fl_ToPlay_4 = !fl_ToPlay_4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to keyboard events at the **stage** level (because all these events eventually bubble to **stage**). Look up the [Keyboard](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Keyboard.html) class for key code references. Keep in mind that keyboard events will trigger the handler only if Flash object (e.g. in browser) has the input focus (for example, you must click it first).

```
var SU:String;
var SA:Sound;
var SC:SoundChannel;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKey);

function onKey(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    // Use trace to get the actual key keycodes or charcodes.
    trace(e.keyCode, e.charCode);

    // After you have all the keys, you need to
    // associate keys with the audio streams.

    var audioURL:String;

    switch (e.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.A:
            audioURL = "audioa.mp3";
            break;

        case Keyboard.B:
            audioURL = "audiob.mp3";
            break;
    }

    // Clean up previous audio.
    if (SC) SC.stop();
    if (SA) SA.close();

    SA = null;
    SC = null;

    // Toggle sound logic.
    if (SU == audioURL)
    {
        SU = null;
    }
    else
    {
        SU = audioURL;
        SA = new Sound(new URLRequest(SU));
        SC = SA.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Eagon No, not really. I just checked, google > **as3 handling keyboard** is full of totally relevant examples, starting with the 1-st result on.